# Heroku with Parse server and swift quetions

Tags: swift, heroku, parse-platform, server

I'm working on an ios app. I choosed "Parse" as my server, and deployed it on "Heroku". I'm totally new to all of these. and I have so many questions:

1. The app needs to have Search Functionality, which allows the user to find something from the database. I'm simply using "query" from "Parse API" to do this, and I know this is not a search engine. So my question is what programming language do I need to to learn in order to write a search engine or just find one from github. And where should I deploy the search engine on, and how can I do it.
2. The app needs to allow users to upload a couple of strings to the server, and I would like to store two versions of the given strings into the database. One is the original string, and the other one is the string without capital letters, punctuations and words like "I, he, she, is, are...". The reason why I need these two versions of strings is to prepare for the Search Functionality, or do I need to? And I know that I can upload the two versions of strings from the app instead of upload one and process it at the backend, but I just want to save the cost of the server. So what programming language do I need to learn to do this, and how can I deploy it on the server?
3. The app also needs to send email and SMS when the user try to sign up. And I choosed "Mailgun" and "Sinch" to help with that. But someone told me that it is unsafe to save all the credentials in my app since people can decompile my app and get those credentials. And his suggestion is to send email and SMS from backend. And the question is here again, what programming language do I need to learn, and how can I deploy it on "Heroku".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is some confusion on your end regarding what Heroku and Parse Server are, so let me try to clarify them.

First of all, in an application there is a front-end and a back-end. The language you are using to code the front end the iPhone (iOS) is either Swift or Objective C- with Swift probably your language.

If you deployed to Heroku using the "Deploy to Heroku" button, you've deployed using Node.js environment, which means your backend (server) language is based on Javascript. Unless your app becomes very complex, you most likely won't need to become an expert at Javascript to make your backend (server) work. Heroku is very easy to use, and most changes that you make to the server will be via Heroku's Add-ons and minimal commands via your Mac terminal.

That being said, you don't need to learn any other language to query your database or to add anything to your database. That's where Parse Server comes in. The engineers at Parse created a SDK that will allow your frontend language (Swift) to communicate with your backend and to make changes to your database. Once you have integrated the SDK to your application (I suggest you use cocoapods to do so), new commands will be available to you on Xcode to query/add items to your database. You don't need to learn any new language, you will just have to become familiar with the new commands available via Parse Server and learn when/how to use them.

Below is the link to Parse Server for iOS. This will be a good place to start for you. With others you are not familiar with (like cocoapods, node.js, npm), google them! There are a lot of good sources out there, and chances are most of your questions are already answered in Stackoverflow.

http://parseplatform.org/docs/ios/guide/

Best of luck to you.